# Download numpy, scipy and matplotlib for pycharm using python 2.7 on windows

Tags: python-2.7, numpy, matplotlib, scipy, pycharm

I have found many many suggestions on how to download these, from using miniconda to using unofficial versions but nothing will work for me? I am just wondering if anyone has any suggestion on a straight forward way I might obtain these as I need them for my project. I am using pycharm with python 2.7 and I have windows 10. Thank you!

Comment: what is wrong with anaconda python ? I would argue against miniconda. You can donwload pycharm frm their website.

Comment: Anaconda should work: https://www.continuum.io/downloads

Comment: As stated above anaconda orminicondashould do the trick. Other options would the Gohlke scientificPython site for windows libs: http://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can find precompiled versions of these libraries for most python versions here:

http://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/#numpy

http://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/#scipy

http://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/#matplotlib

Then do:

```
pip install numpy-something-something.whl
```

This works for me in PyCharm 5.0.3 using Python 3.5.1. Should be the same procedure for 2.7